# scala online code execution

Tags: scala, interpreter

I'd like to develop an web-based application that allows user to submit Scala code from their web browser client and compile / execute their code on the server.

I was trying to use the scala.tools.nsc.IMain / ILoop classes to load the client file and then execute the file on the server.  How do I do this?

How does using the IMain / ILoop classes compare to forking off an external process to compile and execute the code?

Answer (score 2):

Zeppelin is another opensource project worth to take a look at.
It's got scala interpreter embedded for Apache Spark.

https://github.com/NFLabs/zeppelin

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's worth to take a look at https://github.com/Bridgewater/scala-notebook http://vimeo.com/user18356272/review/66548724/53e2b222c1